# For group 7 elements, are anions a lower energy state than being neutral atoms?

Tags: electron-affinity

Given that electron affinity is positive, why don't these atoms attract free electrons and "prefer" to exist as anions?  Never made sense to me — I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: There are no free electrons, much like there is no such thing as a free lunch. Every electron belongs to some entity, which may be more or less unwilling to share it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the electron affinity for group 17 elements (group VII by older IUPAC nomenclature) is generally exothermic, so the uptake of an electron should be favourable.

But as Ivan mentioned in a comment, there is no such thing as a free or lonesome electron. Each electron must first be displaced from another atom — ionised; the corresponding thermodynamic property is the ionisation enthalpy. For *every* element, the ionisation enthalpy is positive, thus it is *always* unfavourable to displace an electron from a neutral atom. No exceptions.

Comment: isn't the first electron affinity of any element (except perhaps noble gases) exothermic?

Comment: @Dissenter No. Manganese, beryllium and nitrogen and possibly others have endothermic EAs